# Endeca baseline update failed emgr_update_get_ws_settings

Tags: linux, endeca

Oracle suspended support on Endeca guided search. Hopefully we can find a former or current Endeca Administrator here that has a lot of knowledge of endeca guided search. We are using endeca MDEX6.2.2 with PlatformsServices6.1.3 on Linux Red Hat enterprise.

Over a week ago our ITL server failed in the baseline_update. 
This happened because there was no space left on the harddrive.
I cleaned up but not enough, causing the Dgidx process to fail.

After more clean up the error was and is this one:

```
SEVERE: Utility 'emgr_update_get_ws_settings' failed. Refer to utility logs 
in [ENDECA_CONF]/logs/shell on host ITLHost.
Occurred while executing line 10 of valid BeanShell script: [[
 7|      if (Forge.isDataReady()) {
 8|        if (ConfigManager.isWebStudioEnabled()) {
 9|          // get Web Studio config, merge with Dev Studio config
10|          ConfigManager.downloadWsConfig();
11|          ConfigManager.fetchMergedConfig();
12|        } else {
13|          ConfigManager.fetchDsConfig();
```

First I had a suberror saying the [ENDECA_CONF]/logs/shell/emgr_update_get_ws_settings.log stating the config directory was missing in /data/webstudio.  I added that and after that the message became  WARNING: System state is ERROR.
No Resources.  Now there is no update_get_ws_settings.log at all.

The workbench is available. And no locks are present.

We need help from an expert endeca admin, financial compensation is possible

Comment: Is the error you show still relevant now that you've updated the file or is there a new error now? Two other things to look at is whether everything is still owned by your endeca user or that your EAC is still behaving (try restarting it once).

Comment: It is still relevant. Currently the baselineupdate still does not run. The error remains the same, with the difference that there is no file [ENDECA_CONF]/logs/shell/emgr_update_get_ws_settings.log  present anymore.  Everything is owned by the endeca user. I did a full reboot of the machine and started everything up but that did not resolve the issue. Maybe I should just stop and restart  the EAC, I just found how to. I will give it a try

Comment: I see lots of issues in the main.0.log and the proces.0;log -> Runner with task id TaskId(UTILITY,avh,emgr_update_get_ws_settings) failed to write status; status is: TaskId(UTILITY,avh,emgr_update_get_ws_settings): Running

Comment: Try running `update_web_studio_config`

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the same error, it was due to my endeca workbench in down state. I tried to restart the workbench service then ran the baseline script to fix the issue.